# Projective tensor product and dense subspaces

Tags: banach-spaces, tensor-products

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach spaces, and let $X \otimes Y$ denote the algebraic tensor product. Then, consider the tensor projective tensor $X \widehat{\otimes}_\pi Y$ as the completion for $X \otimes Y$ with respect to the projective norm
$$
\|f\| = \inf\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \|x_i\|_X \|y_i\|_Y \ : \ f = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \otimes y_i \} \\
= \inf \{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \|x_i\|_X \|y_i\|_Y \ : \ (x_i)_i, \ (y_i)_i \ \mathrm{bounded}, \ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \|x_i\|_X \|y_i\|_Y < \infty, \ f = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i \otimes y_i \}.
$$

QUESTION: If $U$ is a norm-dense subset for $X$, and $V$ is a norm-dense subset for $Y$, are $U \otimes V$ or  $U \widehat{\otimes}_\pi V$ dense in $X \widehat{\otimes}_\pi Y$ with respect to the projective norm?

MY IDEA: if $f = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \otimes y_i$ and
$$
u_i \in U, \ v_i \in V \ \mathrm{satisfy} \ \|x_i - u_i\|_X, \|y_i-v_i\|_Y < \sqrt{\varepsilon}/i,
$$
then the projective norm bounded can be bounded in the following way
$$
\|f - \sum_{i=1}^n u_i \otimes v_i \| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \|x_i - u_i\|_X \ \|y_i - v_i\|_Y \leq \varepsilon \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} \leq \frac{\pi^2}{6} \varepsilon.
$$
And this argument works for every decomposition for $u$.

I cannot find any reference for this fact. Am I missing something?

Edit: Some corrections pointed out by @Hanno. My $\varepsilon$-estimates were incorrect. First, observe that
$$
\| \sum_{i} x_i \otimes y_i - \sum_i u_i \otimes v_i\| = \|\sum_{i} x_i \otimes y_i - x_i \otimes v_i + x_i \otimes v_i - u_i \otimes v_i \| \\
\leq \sum_{i} \|x_i\|_X \|y_i - v_i\|_Y + \sum_{i} \|x_i - u_i\|_X \|v_i\|_Y.
$$
Then, choose $(v_i)_i \subseteq V$ such that
$$
\|y_i - v_i\|_Y \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{i^2 \ \|x_i\|_X }.
$$
By the 'reverse triangular inequality', it follows
$$
\|v_i\|_Y \leq \|y_i\|_Y + \frac{\varepsilon}{i^2 \ \|x_i\|_X},
$$
so choosing $(x_i)_i \subseteq U$ satisfying
$$
\|x_i - u_i\|_X \leq \min\Big\{ \frac{\varepsilon}{i^2 \ \|y_i\|_Y}, \ \|x_i\|_X \Big\}
$$
will do the job.

Comment: $X\hat{\otimes}_{\pi} Y$ and $U\hat{\otimes}_{\pi} V$ are generally two distinct spaces with different norms, so the second part of your question is negative. However the closure of $U\otimes V$ in $X\hat{\otimes}_{\pi} Y$ is equal to $X\hat{\otimes}_{\pi} Y$. Going in steps, 1. every basic tensor $u\otimes y \in U\otimes Y$ is in $\overline{U\otimes V}$. So is their closed linear span. 2. Similarly, every basic tensor $x\otimes v \in X\otimes V$ is in $\overline{U\otimes V}$.

Comment: 3. Any basic tensor $x\otimes y\in X\otimes Y$ now can be shown to be in $\overline{U\otimes V}$. So is their closed linear span $X\hat{\otimes}_{\pi} Y$

Comment: As a general reference for tensor products, please see Ryan's book *Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces* https://books.google.ca/books/?id=MSLUBwAAQBAJ

Comment: Your idea is viable I'd estimate. And it needs refinement at least in the first inequality in the last formulae line, which appears incorrect. Here you shall need something like
$$x\otimes y -u\otimes v = x\otimes (y-v) + (x-u)\otimes v$$
and adapt the choices for the $\epsilon$-bounds.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @OnurOktay ! I think I get the idea. I am working with Ryan's book, but I could not find any explicit reference to this, but Proposition 4.25 (regarding Schauder basis) will work for me actually.

Comment: Thank you so much @Hanno ! I will write the details in the OP.